# Google OR Tools constraints from DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, constraints, or-tools

I would like to build a Google OR Tools model to use `linear_solver` for a `CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING`.
Following [Google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip/integer_opt) I learned hot to build the constraints but I have a question...**is it necessary to hand write every constraint?**
I mean, I have the following DataFrame `df_constraint` which contain the coefficient of the constraints in the form of `ax+by<=c`.

```
+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | 9 | 3 |
| 3 | 0 | 4 |
+---+---+---+
```

the table could be translated into the following contraints

```
# 1x+5y<=7
constraint1 = solver.Constraint(-solver.infinity(), 7)
constraint1.SetCoefficient(x, 1)
constraint1.SetCoefficient(y, 5)

# 2x+9y<=3
constraint2 = solver.Constraint(-solver.infinity(), 3)
constraint2.SetCoefficient(x, 2)
constraint2.SetCoefficient(y, 9)

# 3x<=4
constraint3 = solver.Constraint(-solver.infinity(), 4)
constraint3.SetCoefficient(x, 3)
```

Instead of write every rows I would like something like this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    constraint = solver.Constraint(-solver.infinity(), row['C'])
    constraint.SetCoefficient(x, row['A'])
    constraint.SetCoefficient(y, row['B'])
```

My snippet won't work, as every constraint must have a different name (like `constraint1`, `constraint2`, ...).

Comment: could you create a minimal snippet with complete model and dataframe?

Comment: don't get it you can use a constraint array to store them, if you need to access them outside of the loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, OR-Tools doesn't require each constraint to have a unique name. But the following gives them unique names anyway. As mentioned above, if you need to store the constraints, you can do so in an array as follows. Here I'm using the more common notation (A is the constraint coefficients, B is the constraint right-hand sides, c is the objective coefficients). But it will adapt to your Pandas setup.

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp # adapted from one of the examples

inf = float("inf")

AB = [
    [1, 0, 1], # x <= 1
    [0, 1, 2], # y <= 2
    [1, 1, 2], # x + y <= 2
    [-1, -1, 0] # x + y >= 0
]
c = [3, 1]

def main():
    solver = pywraplp.Solver('simple_lp_program',
                             pywraplp.Solver.GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)
    x = solver.NumVar(-inf, inf, 'x') # no UB or LB on x, y
    y = solver.NumVar(-inf, inf, 'y')

    cts = []
    for i, (*a, b) in enumerate(AB):
        ct = solver.Constraint(-inf, b, 'ct' + str(i))
        ct.SetCoefficient(x, a[0])
        ct.SetCoefficient(y, a[1])
        cts.append(ct)

    print('Number of constraints =', solver.NumConstraints())
    objective = solver.Objective()
    objective.SetCoefficient(x, c[0])
    objective.SetCoefficient(y, c[1])
    objective.SetMaximization()
    solver.Solve()
    print('Solution:')
    print('Objective value =', objective.Value())
    print('x =', x.solution_value())
    print('y =', y.solution_value())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

does this, solve your issue ?

```py
 df_constraints = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': pd.Series([1, 2, 3]),
    'B': pd.Series([5, 9, 0]),
    'C': pd.Series([7, 3, 4]),
    })
for row in df_constraints.itertuples():
    #print("row {}".format(row))
    #print("A {}".format(row[0]))
    #print("B {}".format(row[1]))
    #print("C {}".format(row[2]))
    constraint = solver.Constraint(-solver.infinity(), row[2])
    constraint.SetCoefficient(x, row[0])
    constraint.SetCoefficient(y, row[1])
```