# OR-Tools: add constraints from an array, all at once?

Tags: python, or-tools

I want to minimise *cx* subject to *Ax <= b*. *A*, *b*, and *c* are stored in csv files, numpy arrays, Pandas DataFrames, or whatever. I would like to add all constraints at once. I know that I can use code like the following:

```
for i, (*a, b) in enumerate(AB):
     ct = solver.Constraint(-inf, b, 'ct' + str(i))
     ct.SetCoefficient(x, a[0])
     ct.SetCoefficient(y, a[1])
```

But surely this is not the "right way". I've looked in the examples and docs. Is there a better method? (And can anyone recommend good docs?) If not, the first exercise in the module I'm teaching will be to write a function to import a problem from csv files.

BTW there is [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519478/google-or-tools-constraints-from-dataframe) about adding constraints from a DataFrame, but it is not a duplicate as the goal there is just to achieve the for-loop style. I know how to achieve the for-loop style (and added some code in an answer on that question), but I want a better style.

Comment: I mean, in Excel Solver I can add an entire array of constraints at once. If Excel can do it and Python can't, I'm going to have to re-evaluate everything I know about computer science.

Comment: I wonder what is wrong with the for loop. And in the Excel Solver, there is an hidden loop.

Comment: If you have the standard form and want to enforce batch modelling for whatever reason, a lot of high-lvl modelling tools wont allow that. Their assumptions are: you dont have the standard-form and the time to produce the model is dominated b solving time. Cylp for example would allow the low-level matrix form, also cvxpy, but the latter is somewhat special.

Comment: Last time i checked, you could not even do what you want in the python interface of the leading commercial solver.

Comment: @LaurentPerron, yes, there is a hidden loop. A hidden loop is exactly what it should be -- this is the whole point of vectorised code!

Comment: @sascha, that is really surprising. The scipy interface works that way (but the scipy  method is not as powerful/flexible as OR-Tools or others). https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html

Comment: So I should support all data formats (data frame, XML, SQL, csv, arrays, iterators...) ? I will just pass.

Comment: No, just numpy arrays, of course. Everything else (in Python) goes into that.

Comment: @jmmcd To be honest: there are probably more people wanting this API for scipy.sparse matrices than for numpy-arrays (which makes much more sense).